# How to declare trust array in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm beginner in c#,i want to declare this c# array:

```
double[] array1;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     array1[i]=i;
```

but get error and c# say change that array to this:

```
double[] array1={1.1,2.2};
```

but i have to use my first code,how can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: `double[] array1 = new double[10];`

Comment: thanks my friend,but use that array in c# chart,for example array1[9]=null and in c# chart get error for null value

Comment: use `List<double>.ToArray()` to prevent null in your situation

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi `doubles` cannot be null in C#. If you want them to be nullable, use this instead: `double?[] array1 = new double?[10];`

Comment: You need to explain a lot more than what you have in the question. Edit the question, add the needed details. How does "c# say something"? What chart? There is nothing about a chart there.

Comment: What did the error say and what did you find on google when you searched for that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double[] array1;` only defines the variable, but doesn't instantiate the array.

Do this:

```
double[] array1 = new double[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     array1[i]=i;
```

Comment: thanks my friend,but use that array in c# chart,for example array1[9]=null and in c# chart get error for null value

Comment: your comment isn't clear, and if the answer is not what you wanted, change the question.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net when you initialise an array, you need to provide a size so that memory can be allocated to it.

this is done as such

```
double[] array1 = new double[10];
```

It is also worth noting that Arrays are statically sized so once you create it with that size, if you want it changed you need to create a new array.

Comment: thanks my friend,but use that array in c# chart,for example array1[9]=null and in c# chart get error for null value

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi dont initialise it like that, do it like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
int a = 10;  // the size you want 
array1 = new double[a];
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    array1[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot use your first code because it's not allowed in C#. 
An array needs to know its length when created, and that's why you need to specify its length when creating it.

Also, you must assign it because otherwise, `array1` remains `null`, which means you'll get an error when trying to use it.

So you have two choices here:

- `double[] array1 = new double[10]`, which means "create an array with room for 10 elements and set each value to 0.0", or you say
- `double[] array1 = { 1.0, 2.0, ..., 10.0 };`, which sets the length of the array to the number of the elements you specified, and its values to the ones you specified (1.0-10.0 in the example).

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly number of elements in array you should use arrays. If you're uncertain about that use collection List and cast it to array (or just use it as it is).

Array:

```
double[] array1 = new double[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) array1[i]=i;
```

Collection (don't use it if you know length of your array) :

```
list<double> coll1 = new List<double>();
for(int i=0; i < unknownNumber; i++) coll1.Add(i);
double[] array1 = coll1.ToArray();
```